# how to redirect to url in asp.net core and return to same action for go to view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

My login of website is in other website. in my login action must redirect to url of other website login page.

I use from this code: `return Content("FullUrl");`

This code is OK (redirect page to other website) and after login comeback to my login action in my website. But I need at last return to panel page with this code: `return Content("panel");` but show a blank page that write on "panel".

For a note I Use from this code: `return Content("panel");` in other action and work correctly(show my panel page).

And for other note I use from react for client site of my website.

And last note: I use asp.net core.

Comment: Why did you tag reactjs?

Comment: Because my client side is with react. not with razor

Comment: Use return Redirect, not return Content.

Comment: @RosdiKasim I used return redirect(url) and return to url. But after comeback to my action, I can not go to panel view.